# Inheritance in classes does not work in Python 2.7

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I am trying to improve my understanding of OOP in Python 2.7 (uses in my University courses). My goal is to print the outcome by using a child class. However, I keep getting the below error and do not know how to fix it and why it pops up.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this code and what I am doing wrong?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "*******"", line 36, in <module>
print_grades = CreateReport(ReadFile)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Code:

```
# Constants
input_file = 'grades1.in.txt'

class ReadFile():

def __init__(self):
    self.text_file =''

    def read_file(self, file):
        self.text_file = open(file)

    def data_to_list(self):
        self.list_grades = []
        for x in self.text_file:
            output = x.strip("\n").split("\n")
            temp_list = []
            for y in output:
                temp_list.append(y)
            self.list_grades.append(temp_list)
         return self.list_grades

class CreateReport(ReadFile):
    def __init__(self):
        # ReadFile.__init__(self)
        pass

    def print_list(self):
        data = ReadFile.data_to_list()
        print data

# start_program(input_file)
print_grades = CreateReport(ReadFile)
print_grades.print_list()
```

Comment: You don’t need to pass `ReadFile` as argument when constructing `CreateReport`…!

Comment: The most important thing to know about Python 2.7 at the moment and something I would definitely point out at the course: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @deceze 


Adjusting the code results in the following error:
        TypeError: unbound method data_to_list() must be called with ReadFile 
        instance as first argument (got nothing instead)


class CreateReport():
    def __init__(self):
        # ReadFile.__init__(self)
        pass

    def print_list(self):
        data = ReadFile.data_to_list()
        print data


# start_program(input_file)
print_grades = CreateReport()
print_grades.print_list()

Comment: Yup, 'cause you'd want `self.data_to_list()`.

Comment: Just to note, in Python 2.7, `ReadFile` is an old-style class, because it doesn't inherit explicitly from `object`. Old-style classes have been considered obsolete for years, and only remained supported in later versions of Python 2 for reasons of backwards compatibility. Python 3 doesn't have old-style classes at all, and every class is a new-style class whether or not it explicitly inherits from `object`.